# How can I update Wine, without uninstalling it?

Tags: apt, updates, wine, uninstall

As per title, how can I update Wine without uninstalling it?

Seems a noob question, but it's first time that I find my self to upgrade Wine.

Wine, today it is at the stable version 7.0, and in the past I have installed version 6.0.1 on my computer.
If I write the command `apt search winehq-stable`, this result comes out:

```
winehq-stable / now 6.0.1 ~ hirsute-1 amd64 [installed]
```

(but my version of ubuntu is the following: Ubuntu 21.10 Impish Indri)

And the information I found on internet, related to updating Wine, is always to uninstall Wine to install a new version; Is it possible that you cannot update without uninstalling it?

Besides that seems strange to me, I don't want to lose all the well-set Windows program installations. It would mean starting everything from scratch.
Then I don't understand why from the Wine repository, a new Wine update does not come out and it stays at an old Wine version.

Comment: Sorry about loosing your settings for windows programs but that requirement (uninstalling) is best answered by perhaps the tool owners. Perhaps there's some way to save the settings so you can reapply them.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen, this make me sad....

Comment: @user535733, I corrected about the repositories part..... I know why I chosen the `stable` version of it,  and that is it fine. Except these things of little importance, the main problem it's that cannot be possible to simple upgrade Wine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution, to update Wine, and was simply to add the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ impish main'
```

So, Wine could not find the updates in the Repository and then update it with the latest libraries, because I installed Wine when it was Ubuntu 21.04 Hirsute Hippo ..... after months I installed the latest version of Ubuntu 21.10 Impish Indri. The Wine repository that I added in the past, kept looking for the old Ubuntu version of Wine. So to get around the situation, I simply added the repository corresponding to the version of Ubuntu currently installed in my PC, and the Terminal found the new version of Wine with all related libraries to be updated/installed. Now Wine, it is updated to the latest `Stable` 7.0 version

Comment: Remember to disable or delete the older source; that's not automatic. And keep in mind that you must adjust that Wine source manually after every release-upgrade. This is the maintenance cost of using non-Ubuntu sources.

Answer (score -1):

Uninstalling Wine and deleting the wineprefix are not the same thing. You do not have to delete ~/.wine, but you do have to uninstall 1.6.1 before installing a WineHQ package.

Comment: Wine web site says uninstall and install new version is the only way. This is the second totally wrong answer of yours I have seen today.